# How to pause Firebug logging?

Tags: firefox, firebug

A webpage is continuously generating warnings and pushing the previous warnings up. I can't read the warnings because they keep getting pushed up. How can I pause logging in Firebug?

Comment: Woudl really like to know this as well... THis is incredibly annoying that this is not an obvious feature.